# Remove certain commits from history in a git branch

Tags: git, github

I have a branch `main` and a branch `A` based off `main` that has some commits.

If I now create a new branch `B` based off `A`, create more commits on `B` and during that time, branch `A` gets merged into `main`, then on GitHub, you'll likely see duplicate code when checking the `B` branch pull request into `main` branch. As seen here, this is the `B` pull request, there are the commits from both `A` branch and `B` branch:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWTjO.png]

Is there any way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: just rebase B on `main` should be enough I tink, but not sure to understand your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's visualize your scenario:

```sh
o---o (main)
     \
      A---B (A)
           \
            C---D (B)
```

In Git, a [branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefbranchabranch) is simply a reference to the *latest* of a sequence of commits. [What commits are *in a branch*](https://megakemp.com/2017/04/19/what-is-in-a-git-branch/) depends on which branches you're comparing:

- If you compare `A` with `main`, then `A` has commits `A` and `B` which `main` doesn't have.
- If you compare `B` with `A`, then `B` has commits `C` and `D` which `main` doesn't have.
- If you compare `B` with `main`, then `B` has commits `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` which `main` doesn't have.

Now, if branch `A` were to be merged into `main`, then `main` would also have commits `A` and `B`. This means that if you compare branch `B` with `main` after the merge, then `B` would have commits `C` and `D` that aren't in `main`:

```
o---o-------M (main)
     \     /
      A---B (A)
           \
            C---D (B)  <-- these commits aren't in 'main'
```

The fact that GitHub is showing you commits from branch `A` when you do a pull request from branch `B` to `main` makes me think that branch `A` was [*rewritten*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) (possibly rebased) after you created branch `B`:

```
o---o---o--------M (main)
     \   \      /
      \   A'---B' (A)      <-- rebased commits in branch 'A'
       \ 
        A---B---C---D (B)  <-- branch 'B' still has the old commits
```

If this is indeed the case, the solution is simply to [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) branch `B` on top of `main` and update the pull request:

```
o---o---o--------M (main)
         \      / \
          A'---B'  \
               ^    \
              (A)    C---D (B)
```

Git will notice that the changes from commits `A` and `B` are already in `main` thanks to commits `A'` and `B'` and will therefore only show you commits `C` and `D` when you compare branch `B` to `main`.